# How many combinations this bin packing problem has?

Tags: python, combinations, bin-packing

Let's say we have a set of 100 videos that contain 10 to 30 frames, and we want to group them in n groups such as the total number of frames of each group are approximatively equal. Moreover, every frame belonging to one video has to be part of a unique group.

**First**, is it possible to know the number of possible combinations knowing that the order has no importance?
For simplicity, let's say we have only 6 videos {1,2,3,4,5,6} with an equal number of frames and we want to group them into n=2 groups.

> 0 -> (1,2,3) (4,5,6)
>  1 -> (1,2,4) (3,5,6)
>  2 -> (1,2,5)
> (3,4,6)
>  3 -> (1,2,6) (3,4,5)
>  4 -> (1,3,4) (2,5,6)
>  5
> -> (1,3,5) (2,4,6)
>  6 -> (1,3,6) (2,4,5)
>  7 -> (2,3,4) (1,5,6)
>  8 -> (2,3,5) (1,4,6)
>  9 -> (2,3,6) (1,4,5)

So by hand, I found 10 possible groups. 
Is there a formula that describes this process?

**Second**, is there a way to solve this problem without brut force?

My first guess is to randomly create n groups and choose the best group such as its number of frames per group standard deviation is the lowest.

Here is my brute force solution in Python:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)

n_group = 7
nr_videos = 100
iterations = 1000

video_dataset = np.random.randint(10,30, nr_videos)

# Total number of frames
total_frames = np.sum(video_dataset)

# Optimal number of frames per bin
target_frames_per_bin = total_frames/n_group

# Array containing every standard deviation
std_array = np.zeros(iterations, dtype=float)

# Array containing the number of frame for each bin at one iteration
nr_frames_per_bin = np.zeros(n_group, dtype=int)

for i in range(iterations):
    # Shuffle the video dataset
    seed = i
    np.random.seed(i)
    new_video_dataset = np.array(video_dataset)
    np.random.shuffle(new_video_dataset)

    # Reset the array
    nr_frames_per_bin *= 0

    # Pack each bin consecutively
    bin_n = 0
    for j in range(nr_videos):
        if(nr_frames_per_bin[bin_n] > target_frames_per_bin):
            bin_n += 1
        nr_frames_per_bin[bin_n] += new_video_dataset[j]

    # Compute the std for the current bin
    std_array[i] = np.std(nr_frames_per_bin)

best_seed = np.argmin(std_array)
best_std = std_array[best_seed]

print("Best iteration:", best_seed)
print("Best std:", np.round(best_std,2))
```

Please let me know if I'm clear enough.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Bin-pacing is NP-complete, so there is no known polynomial-time algorithm that solves it optimally. That said, there are simple approximation algorithms that provide fast packings that pack items using no more than twice as many bins as necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @chepner; I'll check for an optimized package. Nevertheless, do you know how many combinations are possible given this example? My guess will be something like n^100 if every video has an equal number of frames. However, how can I approximate this number, given that videos don't have equal frames?

Comment: You can probably compute upper and lower bounds on the number of feasible solutions, but I'm not sure why you would care about the actual number (short of this being an exercise in combinatorics).

Comment: I run 100 million iterations to achieve a good result in the original problem. But, as it seems a lot, I wanted to show the reason behind such a number. So, estimating all possible combinations would give a quick overview of the problem. Do you have any idea where I can find related material? I haven't done any combinatoric in my school curriculum.